# Looping through Array and assigning values to variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I haven't got any code yet, as I was just wondering if it is possible to loop through an `Array` that is dynamically populated to the amount of values could be different each time. The variables would obviously have to make use of an incrementing value?

Comment: yes this possible... but can you clarify a bit better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and have a look at the examples.

Comment: Where should the array values go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [array length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property to work with an unknown array lengths:

```
var arr = ["carrots", "bananas", "onions"];

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    //every element accesible via arr[i];
    //example:
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

That will loop through the whole array even if it there are more or less elements on it

With this base, I am sure you can do what you want from here

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure by now you've probably figured it out, but I'll just add this here for any future Javascript beginners.

Javascript Arrays have a built-in function called `forEach` allowing you to iterate over every element in an array. It functions as a loop specifically meant for Arrays. It takes a callback function as an argument and looks like the following:

```
let stringArr = ['dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'elephant'];

stringArr.forEach(function(element, counter) {
    console.log(counter+') '+element);
});

// Outputs:
   0) dog
   1) cat
   2) lion
   3) elephant
```

The callback function can, of course be replaced by an arrow function, if you'd like, but as you can see the first argument in the callback function (`element`) is the element in the array, and the second argument (`counter`) keeps track of the index of the element in the array.

What I love about the `forEach` is that it makes accessing the array elements easier (even if only somewhat) than using a standard `for-loop`. For instance when looping through objects with a `for-loop`, to access the individual elements in the array one would have to do `myArray[i].property`, but using the `forEach`, one can simply do `element.property`.

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) some additional reading on the `forEach` if it still hasn't quite clicked yet.